# Best approach to build a dashboard

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard, amazon-athena

Looking for some advice... just finished a ETL pipeline where all data ends up in Amazon Athena. The data is produced via the click stream of high volume mobile apps (so essentially it’s lots and lots of raw events). I want to build a number of dashboards for the business that show different metrics/KPIs depending on the requirements. However, since we’re talking about huge volumes of data I’m not sure the best way to do this? Here’s an example:

I want a dashboard that shows all the MAUs (monthly active users), along with certain pages that perform particularly well and the most popular navigation routes through the app. My thinking is that I’d want a custom query per graph I.e. one query that is counting the distinct IDs each day (and then refreshing every 24hr)... another query for a graph that produces a breakdown of counts per page and truncates... etc
The main reason for thinking this is otherwise I’d be pulling in huge amounts of raw data just to calculate a simple metric like MAUs (not even sure extract would work - certainly wouldn’t be efficient).

Is this completely the wrong approach? Any suggestions/feedback?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have multiple unrelated SQL queries that you want to run once per day, and update in Tableau once per day.

There's always a pull-push between the processing at the source and in the visualization engine.

Set up a Tableau server extract for each Athena SQL query. Build your dashboards, and schedule your extracts to refresh daily. Like an OLAP cube, this will process all the aggregates your dashboards need with the refresh, for better dashboard performance.

Alternatively, if you feel you don't need all the detail in Tableau, then build your aggregates in SQL, so that your Tableau data sources are smaller.